# Automating the creation of new GitHub repository from cmd

Tags: python, rest, github, curl

I want to create a new GitHub repository using the command line on Windows with Python, I'm new to the API concept, and I know about using Hub to do this same thing, but I want to use the code I wrote myself. This is my code:

```
#########################################
# AUTHOR: Dennis Lucius
# DATE: 19/10/2022
# GITHUB: https://github.com/denstream-io
#########################################

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from subprocess import call
from os import getenv

# new-repo (username) (reponame) (mode)
# todo: covert to exe add to path

if not (PAT := getenv("PAT")):
    raise RuntimeError("Github Acess token no set")

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Creates new Github repository")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-n", "--new", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("username", help="Github username")
parser.add_argument("repository", help="Repository name")
parser.add_argument("description", help="Repository description")
parser.add_argument("mode", help="private true or false")
args = parser.parse_args()

call(
    f' curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <{PAT}>" \
  https://api.github.com/user/repos \
  -d "{{"name":{args.repository},"description": {args.description},"homepage":"https://github.com","private":{args.mode.islower()},"is_template":true}}"',
    shell=True,
)
print("Done Creating Repo")

if args.new:
    cmds = (
        "git init",
        f"git remote add origin git@gtihub.com:{args.username}/{args.repository}.git",
        "git add .",
        "git commit -m 'first commit'",
        "git push -u -f origin master",
    )
    for cmd in cmds:
        call(cmd, shell=True)
```

But each time I run the code this error pops up:

```
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

How do I resolve it?

Got inspiration from this shell script:
[Jeo-a-d](https://github.com/Joe-a-d/CLI/tree/master/git-new)
and this article: [replacing-bash-scripting-with-python](https://github.com/ninjaaron/replacing-bash-scripting-with-python)

Comment: If you're going to write this in Python, you should probably use something like the `requests` module rather than calling out to `curl` for your http transactions.

Comment: Is this why I'm getting the error?

Comment: `<{PAT}>` I don't think it should be enclosed in `<>`

Comment: I removed the "<>" and got this error after re-running the code:
```{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}```

Comment: Are you able to run this `curl` command on the command prompt, outside your script? If so, print the command before running it and make sure it's the same both ways, at least for the PAT part of the command.

Comment: Yes ```curl``` runs on the cmd, but how do I "print the command"?

Comment: you can define the cURL request as a string first, and then print it before sending.